# How to change the coupon code success message Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, coupon-codes

How do I change the coupon code message?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Either you can edit directly file where this message comes i.e

copy:

> /vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/js/action/cancel-coupon.js

to

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_SalesRule/web/js/action/cancel-coupon.js

**+++++++++OR+++++++++**

You can add translation for message i.e

Create `en_US.csv` at

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/i18n/en_US.csv

and put your required message in above file